# Google Wallet: How to include the order ID in the success_handler?

Tags: php, javascript, android-pay

I am implementing Google Wallet for Digital Goods in a website, using PHP and HTML/JavaScript.

Google will wait 10 seconds for the postback.php to respond with 200/ok and to output the order ID. If that has happened, it will charge the Credit Card and call the success_handler function. After 10 seconds of no response however it will cancel the transaction and trigger the failure_handler function.

I want to protect myself from my server being slow and only want to deliver the digital good if the success_handler has been called. To prevent fraud  i need to verify if the order ID was correct (because the successhandler is client side).

**How do I get the order ID of the transaction into the success_handler, so that I can verify it in my system and if all matches be sure that I received the money and deliver the digital good?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you point out, to prevent fraud, you need to check with your server that the transaction calling the success handler matches a corresponding postback call made to your server.

You will need to match the order Ids returned by the two callbacks. The order Id is part of the jwt returned in the success handler or server postback (under "response"->"orderId"):

https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/digital/docs/jsreference#successhandler

Comment: Perfect! So the success/failure handler functions contain a result parameter `success_handler = function(result)`, which holds all the necessary information (especially order ID or error type). From there I can call `result['response']['orderId']` as well as `result['request']['sellerData']`. Makes sense! :-) Thanks a lot

Comment: I believe in the link you gave the information about the failure handler is not quite accurate. From what this documentation says I would think `failure_handler= function(result)` would give me `result['request']['sellerData']` and `result['response']['errorType']`. The later is correct but for the seller data and any values in that "layer" of the object are under `result['request']['request']['price']` (one additional 'request' layer). Or am I reading something wrong?